# How to resize Images / SVG based on available space (height) when using grid and fr units

Tags: css

I need to make a page that is only 100vh + 100vw. **No Scroll allowed.** I have created a layout with `grid` and a lot of `fr` units (I cannot use fixed heights/widths because there is some text which need to be `auto`). Now I do have a problem, when I have images or SVGs, they are scaling based on their width and not their height. (I need them to both scale based on available width and/or height.

Here is a very simplified version of my case. The real one has way more elements and grids in grids etc.

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  height: 100dvh;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;

  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr;
}

.images {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 1fr);
}

.img-wrapper {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: aqua;
  padding: 30px;

  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}

svg {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolores fugit
  incidunt, dolorem pariatur dolor error praesentium eius, necessitatibus
  ratione architecto eaque maxime vel nemo nisi amet quod corporis et
  accusamus corrupti. Assumenda veniam recusandae sed, similique nam omnis
  vel quidem in, inventore animi nihil laudantium rem fuga amet officia
  officiis. Aliquam, ullam corporis optio est aspernatur dolorum voluptas
  deleniti nam magni cumque vel quae ducimus cupiditate quaerat placeat
  earum nobis totam necessitatibus obcaecati libero commodi at. Ea
  aspernatur consectetur neque excepturi consequuntur beatae laborum quis
  accusantium, blanditiis aliquid unde cupiditate quod tempore reprehenderit
  magnam similique veniam iure saepe. Dignissimos, adipisci!
</div>

<div class="images">
  <div class="img-wrapper">
    <svg
         viewBox="0 0 32 32"
         version="1.1"
         xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
         >
      <title>alt-battery-1</title>
      <path
            d="M0 20q0 2.496 1.76 4.256t4.256 1.76h17.984q2.496 0 4.256-1.76t1.76-4.256h1.984v-8h-1.984q0-2.464-1.76-4.224t-4.256-1.76h-17.984q-2.496 0-4.256 1.76t-1.76 4.224v8zM4 20v-8q0-0.832 0.576-1.408t1.44-0.576h17.984q0.832 0 1.408 0.576t0.608 1.408v8q0 0.832-0.608 1.44t-1.408 0.576h-17.984q-0.832 0-1.44-0.576t-0.576-1.44zM6.016 20h1.984v-8h-1.984v8z"
            ></path>
    </svg>
  </div>
  <div class="img-wrapper">
    <svg
         viewBox="0 0 32 32"
         version="1.1"
         xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
         >
      <title>alt-battery-1</title>
      <path
            d="M0 20q0 2.496 1.76 4.256t4.256 1.76h17.984q2.496 0 4.256-1.76t1.76-4.256h1.984v-8h-1.984q0-2.464-1.76-4.224t-4.256-1.76h-17.984q-2.496 0-4.256 1.76t-1.76 4.224v8zM4 20v-8q0-0.832 0.576-1.408t1.44-0.576h17.984q0.832 0 1.408 0.576t0.608 1.408v8q0 0.832-0.608 1.44t-1.408 0.576h-17.984q-0.832 0-1.44-0.576t-0.576-1.44zM6.016 20h1.984v-8h-1.984v8z"
            ></path>
    </svg>
  </div>
</div>
```

I would like that the 2 SVGs decrease their height until they fit in the viewport.

I got a working version when I set the heights/width explicitly but then I loose all the nice things that grid and fr units gave me.